# Filter Hardware Printers | Get-Printer cmdlet | PowerShell

Tags: powershell

The cmdlet `Get-Printer` retrieves a list of printers installed on a computer.

The cmdlet also shows software printers (eg *Microsoft Print to PDF*) that I want to exclude.

Is there a way to filter hardware printers ️?

Comment: Get-Help Get-Printer -Full  or  Get-Help Get-Printer -Online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Combining select-string and -notmatch operator you can achieve this. Also please try to add what you have tried to get desired results.  Here is a sample for you

```
Get-Printer | Where-Object {$_.Name | Select-String -notmatch "Fax","Microsoft"}
```

Comment: Now my script disables the Print Spooler service only if it does not find a hardware printer! Thanks bro.